# Turning off autoProcessQueue in Dropzone.js causes null files to be submitted

Tags: java, struts, dropzone.js

I am using Dropzone.js to upload images to a Struts 1 application as part of sending a message. If I allow Dropzone to automatically process each file, then it gets correctly passed into the Action and I can save it to the disk.

However, this process must be deferred so that the author can verify the content of their message/attachments before deciding to send the message. If I set autoProcessQueue to false, and then try to upload later via a button that calls processQueue() or a submit button for the form, my Action only receives a null file.

struts-config.xml:

```
<form-bean name="patientPortalAttachmentUploadForm" type="org.apache.struts.validator.DynaValidatorForm">
    <form-property name="attachment" type="org.apache.struts.upload.FormFile" />
</form-bean>
...
<action     path="/patient/portalmsg/send/attachments"
            type="com.communitect.ui.UploadAction"
            name="patientPortalAttachmentUploadForm"
            scope="request"
            parameter="portalmsg"
           input="/patient_view.jsp">
  <set-property property="secure" value="true"/>
  <forward name="success" path="/patient/view.do" redirect="true"/>
</action>
```

JSP Page:

```
<html:form action="/patient/portalmsg/send/attachments" 
    styleClass="dropzone"   
    styleId="dropzone">
  <html:button styleId="submit-all">Submit all files</html:button> 
</html:form>

....

    Dropzone.options.dropzone = {
    maxFiles: 2,
    addRemoveLinks:true,
    autoProcessQueue:false,
    paramName: "attachment",
    init: function() {
      var submitButton = document.querySelector("#submit-all")
          myDropzone = this; // closure

      submitButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        myDropzone.processQueue(); // Tell Dropzone to process all queued files.
      })
    }

};
```

UploadAction.java

```
public final class UploadAction extends CustomAction
{
   @Override
   protected ActionForward executePostUser(
    ActionMapping mapping,
    ActionForm form,
    HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response,
    User user ) throws IOException, ServletException, JSONException
   {
        DynaValidatorForm patientPortalAttachmentUploadForm = (DynaValidatorForm) form;

        FormFile file = (FormFile) patientPortalAttachmentUploadForm.get( "attachment" );
        System.out.println("AttachmentName: " + file.getFileName() );
```

The way I understood the documentation, delaying the processing of the files should not cause any other change in the way this plugin functions and handles files.

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: Can you use that function when the autoprocess is false?